# Trying to migrate Alamofire 3 requests to version 4 with headers

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to migrate these type of calls:

```
let request = Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .put, parameters: ["password" : newPassword], encoding: .json, headers: ServiceManager.authorizationHeaders()).validate().responseJSON {
```

To the Alamofire 4.0.0 syntax but no matter what I try, I get 'extra argument in call'.

I checked the documentation and can't see where I'm going wrong, nor can I find an example of how to set the headers on the new version - apologies in advance if I missed that part.

Thanks for any advice.

Gareth.

Comment: Currently I am having the same issue too.
You can read this thread
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508

Answer (score 3):

This works for me
**Swift 3.0**

```
 Alamofire.request("https://yourServiceURL.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(response.result.value)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break

        }
    }
```

and make sure the **parameters** are of type

```
[String:Any]?
```